# Are there any racial differences in Starbound?

Tags: starbound

Are there any differences between the different races in Starbound, besides starting items and how their equipment look?

Answer (score 3):

Two minor details that I know of:

- <kbd>N</kbd> (Scan) descriptions are different. E.g., Floransss often relate to hunting thingsss and adding extra sss'sss.
- All races start with "local" recipes, having to learn or find items from other races. This means that Tier'd armor made from the forge will be different per-race (but the stats are the same).

Comment: There's a mod one can install to add more differences. http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=729492334

Comment: Downvoting unless you edit, because as of now on 1.0 I'm a Hyotl and my first quest was to find clues of the Floran artifact. And another improvement: foods are affected. That are some fruits that are poisonous to some races, while others can eat without any debuff.

Comment: @DH. Whoops, so it is. Updated.